# Jest throwing timeout error for video element

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a function which extracts meta data like width and height from video element as following:

```
export async function getVideoMetadata(
  videoBlobUrl: string,
  videoElement: HTMLVideoElement,
): Promise<{ width: number; height: number }> {
  // Trigger video load
  return new Promise<{ width: number; height: number }>((resolve, reject) => {
    videoElement.onloadedmetadata = () => {
      videoElement.width = videoElement.videoWidth;
      videoElement.height = videoElement.videoHeight;
      videoElement.currentTime = videoElement.duration * 0.25;
    };

    videoElement.onseeked = () => {
      resolve({ width: videoElement.videoWidth, height: videoElement.videoHeight });
    };

    videoElement.onerror = () => {
      reject(`Error loading video`);
    };
    videoElement.src = videoBlobUrl;
  });
}
```

On a running environment, the code runs perfectly and provides desired result with the correct height and width of video. I am using this function in another function to draw the video on canvas to generate thumbnail of the video on client side.

But when I am trying to write a test in jest for the same as the following function:

```
  it('should return video metadata', async () => {
    // Mock the videoBlobUrl
    const videoBlobUrl = 'https://example.com/mock-video-url.mp4';

    // Mock the HTMLVideoElement
    const videoElementMock: HTMLVideoElement = {
      onloadedmetadata: null,
      onseeked: null,
      onerror: null,
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
      videoWidth: 640, // Mock video width
      videoHeight: 480, // Mock video height
      duration: 10, // Mock video duration
      currentTime: 0,
      src: '',
      addEventListener: jest.fn(),
      removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
      dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
      play: jest.fn(),
      pause: jest.fn(),
      load: jest.fn(),
    };

    // Spy on addEventListener to capture the event handlers
    const addEventListenerSpy = jest.spyOn(videoElementMock, 'addEventListener');

    // Call the function with the mocked data
    const result = await getVideoMetadata(videoBlobUrl, videoElementMock);

    // Assertions
    expect(videoElementMock.src).toBe(videoBlobUrl);
    expect(addEventListenerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('loadedmetadata', expect.any(Function));
    expect(addEventListenerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('seeked', expect.any(Function));

    // Trigger the loadedmetadata event
    const loadedMetadataHandler = (addEventListenerSpy as jest.Mock).mock.calls.find(
      (call) => call[0] === 'loadedmetadata',
    )[1] as EventListener;
    loadedMetadataHandler(new Event('loadedmetadata'));

    // Trigger the seeked event
    const seekedHandler = (addEventListenerSpy as jest.Mock).mock.calls.find(
      (call) => call[0] === 'seeked',
    )[1] as EventListener;
    seekedHandler(new Event('seeked'));

    // Validate the result
    expect(result).toEqual({width:640, height:480});
  });
```

The test case always fails throwing out as soon as I call `getVideoMetadata` function in the test case without proceeding to the next line.

```
    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
```

I have tried increasing the timeout of the test but that did not help. As soon as the test code `videoElement.src = videoBlobUrl;` reaches and the next step it fails throwing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You attached the event handlers to the video element by its properties `.onloadedmetadata`, `.onseeked`, and `.onerror`. They are all anonymous functions rather than jestjs **mock** functions. So `jest.spyOn(videoElementMock, 'addEventListener')` and `expect(addEventListenerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('loadedmetadata', expect.any(Function))` will not work.

Since you passed the `videoElement` to `getVideoMetadata` function, modify the video element's properties when the event happens, and you can get the properties(event handlers) of the video element in the tests. Then trigger them manually.

E.g.

`getVideoMetadata.test.ts`:

```
import { expect, it } from '@jest/globals';
import { getVideoMetadata } from './getVideoMetadata';

it('should return video metadata', async () => {
  const videoBlobUrl = 'https://example.com/mock-video-url.mp4';

  const videoElementMock = {
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    videoWidth: 640,
    videoHeight: 480,
    duration: 10,
    currentTime: 0,
    src: '',
    onloadedmetadata: () => {},
    onseeked: () => {},
  };

  const promise = getVideoMetadata(videoBlobUrl, videoElementMock as unknown as HTMLVideoElement);

  expect(videoElementMock.src).toBe(videoBlobUrl);

  // Trigger the loadedmetadata event
  videoElementMock.onloadedmetadata();

  // Trigger the seeked event
  videoElementMock.onseeked();

  // Validate the result
  const result = await promise;
  expect(result).toEqual({ width: 640, height: 480 });
  expect(videoElementMock.src).toBe(videoBlobUrl);
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/77550452/getVideoMetadata.test.ts
  ✓ should return video metadata (1 ms)

---------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                 | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files            |      90 |      100 |      80 |      90 |                   
 getVideoMetadata.ts |      90 |      100 |      80 |      90 | 15                
---------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.553 s
```

Comment: Thanks @Lin Du for the assistance. Worked like a charm.